# TYPO3: Difference between Plugin and Custom Content Element?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, extbase

I have to implement a media download feature. The backend user should be able to upload a media file, set the title, description, release date and so on... The result should then be visible and the file available for download in the frontend.

I am not sure what is the best way to achieve this: Plugin or Custom content element ?
Whats the main difference between the two and what would be the best solution for my task ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugins are used for more complex rendering of records with different views (for example a list and a detail view of records stored somewhere in a storage folder). A custom content element (CE) should be preferred if all relevant data is stored in the record.

For your case, a Content Element seems to be the right solution. This kind of custom content elements can also be easily created with helpful extensions like "mask" which may takes you 10 minutes to create a custom CE.
https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/mask

Comment: Ok thanks. I tried the mask extension but I don't think it provides enough features for my task. I have to create a "Preview" and generate a watermark over it and some other stuff. I guess I have to use a custom CE and a DataProcessor ?

Comment: For a image with a watermark you can create a Typoscript object and then call it inside Fluid with f:cOject. A DataProcessor is of course also possible. If it's getting to complex, you may create an extension with plugin ;-)

Comment: I think I will choose the plugin solution as it is more future proof, we never know :)

Comment: @Paul Beck: I would modify your answer from "...(CE) should be preffered for simply viewing some texts or images without the need of complex logics" to "...(CE) should be preferred if all relevant data is stored in the record." Other records could be referred, but in a static way and not dynamic like "do a query and show all" or "show record with uid given in URL". and the rendering might include complex logics. You even can provide new viewhelpers as the CE should be provided in an extension so it can be transferred easier to another installation.

Comment: Thanks Bernd Wilke you are right. Ever since Processors have been added to FLUIDTEMPLATE, you can of course perform complex logics inside custom CEs.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you properly.
You can define plugin as type of "list_type", or as "CType" (if you need to code specific function, which is hard or unable to achieve using eg. Fluid contents) or even as another menu type defined as "menu_type".

These all types can be the same way made plugin, this separation for types are basically only for making it appear in different selectors. So:

- your plugin defined as menu_type is to be selected in "Special Menus" content type in "Menu type" selector,
- defined as list_type (so called) is to be selected in "Insert Plugin" content in "Selected plugin" selector,
- defined as CType is totally new content type.

But they work the same way and this is easily to be switched using parameter in ext_tables plugin register call:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPlugin( ['Label', $_EXTKEY.'_myPluginSuffix'], 'CType');
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a useful explanation as I was always wondering where the different plugin types are used for, or how they are different from each other. Also in newer versions it seems only CType and list_type are available.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use the "File Link" content element and adapt its TypoScript (`tt_content.uploads.20.renderObj`) to your needs.

2) You can use the [file_list](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/file_list) extension and adapt its Fluid templates to your needs